# pseudo inverse of a holomorphic multivariate injective map

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $f:{\mathbb C}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb C}^N$, $N > n$, be holomorphic and injective on an open ball $B_n \subset {\mathbb C}^n$ such that the Jacobian matrices have full column rank at each point in the closure of $B_n$. Set $f(B_n)=V$ and let $B_N \subset {\mathbb C}^N$ be the minimum radius open ball containing $V$. I’m looking for a proof that there exist a holomorphic map $g:B_N\rightarrow {\mathbb C}^n$ such that $g \circ f=I$ on $B_n$.

Comment: Without more hypothesis, $g$ need not exist.  Consider $f(z) = (z^2,z^3)$ with $(n,N)=(1,2)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant I mistakenly assumed that injectivity implies full Jacobian column rank on $B_n$. I will edit to add this condition as this is the case I'm interested in.